# How can I identify RSA Private key uniquely in C#

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle, sha

I am using bouncy castle `RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameter` to read RSA private key. 
I want to get some property to identify the RSA private key uniquely.

privateKey = bytes of the RSA privatekey

```
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(privateKey))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaPrivatekey;

        var privateKeyObject = new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
        rsaPrivatekey = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters) privateKeyObject;

        //KeyId = here some property of rsaPrivatekey to indentify this key uniquely 
    }
}
```

I am casting the `rsaPrivatekey` to `Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters`. 
Can I use any of this class property to identify the key uniquely?

Can I use any of this methods - DP, DQ, P, PublicExponent, Q, QInv or GetHashCode
to get the unique data to indentify the key.

**My requirment is to get human readable string from the rsa key (like KeyId) so has to identify each rsa key uniquely. It might be some KeyId or thumbprint/fingureprint**

Comment: Can I use any of below methods  
DP, DQ, P, PublicExponent, Q, QInv or GetHashCode

Comment: Can you share more code to get a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: added code for better understanding

Comment: You can use a dictionary of `Dictionary<string, RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters> rsaPrivatekeys` to keep a track of it?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, can you just do a key value pair <Guid, key> ?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: for just identify to the key.

Comment: @SagarDhanve Your question is incomplete. To "identify" the key is simple if you have a table with two columns. One being a simple counting index and the second being the private key raw bytes. I think you need to be more clear about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Sentinel Actually I have stored private key raw bytes in the table, I want some unique identity from a private key in string format. So the user can differentiate the keys easily while I display records on the screen. For example: In pgp key, using the **Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp GetFingerprint** function we can get the fingerprint for the pgp key, can we do something for RSA key?

Comment: @SagarDhanve Why not just use the row index? Or some arbitrary sequence of characters not related to the key in any way other than that they are in the table row together.

Comment: @Sentinel I can create some arbitrary sequence to identify the key uniquely, but I am trying to get some unique data from RSA key itself.

Comment: @Sagar Dhanve You have not explained why. What is wrong with the key position. If you want to make an identifier based on the private key, you can use the public key or a secure hash, as described below. But that could be pretty user unfriendly.

Answer (score 1):

He is wanting to store the Private keys, but give them an index parameter that is unique based on the content of the key.

In which case- I would recommend using Sha256 hashing of the private or public key associated with the private key, and then store both in a database.

Answer (score 1):

If the public exponent is fixed (usually 65537) you should just use some of the low-order bits of the public key modulus to form an index, but don't bother with the very lowest-order bit because it's always "1". This is of course very fast.

By using only the public key you don't risk leaking information about the private key into the index. If you are storing both private and public keys in the same database then you can do something like append a "1" bit then take the original index and append either a "1" bit or a "0" bit depending on whether the public or private key is being indexed.